# Rank country by crop using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
,Area,Item,Year,Unit,Value

524473,Ecuador,Sesame,2018,tonnes,16.0
524602,Ecuador,Sorghum,2018,tonnes,14988.0
524776,Ecuador,Soybeans,2018,tonnes,25504.0
524907,Ecuador,Spices nes,2018,tonnes,746.0
525021,Ecuador,Strawberries,2018,tonnes,1450.0
525195,Ecuador,Sugar beet,2018,tonnes,4636.0
525369,Ecuador,Sugar cane,2018,tonnes,7502251.0
...
1075710,Mexico,Tomatoes,2018,tonnes,4559375.0
1075865,Mexico,Triticale,2018,tonnes,25403.0
1076039,Mexico,Vanilla,2018,tonnes,495.0
1076213,Mexico,"Vegetables, fresh nes",2018,tonnes,901706.0
1076315,Mexico,"Vegetables, leguminous nes",2018,tonnes,75232.0
1076469,Mexico,Vetches,2018,tonnes,93966.0
1076643,Mexico,"Walnuts, with shell",2018,tonnes,159535.0
1076817,Mexico,Watermelons,2018,tonnes,1472459.0
1076991,Mexico,Wheat,2018,tonnes,2943445.0
1077134,Mexico,Yautia (cocoyam),2018,tonnes,38330.0
1077308,Mexico,Cereals (Rice Milled Eqv),2018,tonnes,35974485.0
```

In DataFrame there are all countries of the world and all agriculture products.
That's what i want to do:

1. Choose country, for example France.
2. Find the place of France in the world ranking for the production of a particular crop.

And so on all crops.

France ranks 1 in the world in oats production.

France ranks 2 in the world in cucumber production.

France ranks 2 in the world in rye production.

France ranks .... and so on on each product if France produces it.

I started with

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Item')['Value'].idxmax()]
```

but I need not only first place, but the second, third, fourth.... Help me please.

I am very new in pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a rank column:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('Item')['Value'].rank(ascending=False)
```

and then extract information for a country with:

```
df[df['Area']=='France']
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with `rank`

```
s = df.groupby('Item')['Value'].rank(ascending = False)
```

Then

```
d = { x : y  for x , y in df.groupby(s)}

d[1] # output put rank one
```